# Lex yacc Shift/Reduce error

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex, operator-precedence

I am learning lex and yacc programming and this yacc program to validate and evaluate arithmetic expression in giving me 25shift/reduce conflicts. After reading other stackoverflow explanations, I understand the the issue is precedence, however, I am not sure how to resolve using error handling. I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have tried an Association handler like this:

```
%token VARNAME
%token DIGIT
%token EQ
%token ADD SUB MULT DIV
%token LPAREN RPAREN
%token END
%left ADD SUB MULT DIV LPAREN
%right RPAREN END
%nonassoc EQ VARNAME DIGIT
```

But, it doesn't work and I'm confused.  This is my 1.y file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    extern FILE *yyin;
    extern int yylex();
    extern int yyparse();
    extern int yydebug;

    yydebug = 1;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!fp)
        {
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            yyin = fp;
            yyparse();
            fprintf (stdout, "***PARSE COMPLETE***\n");
        }
    }
    else 
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
}

void yyerror (const char *err)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Error: %s\n", err);
}

%}

%token VARNAME
%token DIGIT
%token EQ
%token ADD SUB MULT DIV
%token LPAREN RPAREN
%token END

%%
    statement:
    END
    |
    expression END  
    {printf ("DONE!\n");};
    |
    error 
    { printf(" INVALID EXPRESSION\n"); }
;

expression: 
    VARNAME 
    {printf("PARSED A VARIABLE!\n");};
    |
    DIGIT 
    {printf("PARSED A DIGIT!\n");};
    |
    expression ADD expression
    {printf("PARSED A PLUS SIGN!\n");};
    |
    expression SUB expression
    {printf("PARSED A MINUS SIGN!\n");};
    |
    expression MULT expression
    {printf("PARSED A MULTPLY SIGN!\n");};
    |
    expression DIV expression
    {printf("PARSED A DIVIDE SIGN!\n");};
    |
    expression EQ expression
    {printf("PARSED A EQUALS SIGN!\n");};
    |
    LPAREN expression RPAREN
    {printf("PARSED A PARENTHESIS!\n");};
    ;

%%
```

I have tried an Association handler like this:

```
%token VARNAME
%token DIGIT
%token EQ
%token ADD SUB MULT DIV
%token LPAREN RPAREN
%token END
%left ADD SUB MULT DIV LPAREN
%right RPAREN END
%nonassoc EQ VARNAME DIGIT
```

Is this association correct?

Comment: You need to specify the precedence and associativity of the operators.  Look up `%left`, `%right` and `%nonassoc`.  Or write the grammar in a different manner altogether.  For example, the grammar in the C standard doesn't need the precedence levels or associativity.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was having trouble with the formatting, but I updated the post with my attempt.  Have I associated the DIGITS, EQ, and VARNAME correctly?

Comment: The `%token` items look plausible.  I think `%left` does not need `LPAREN`; nor does `%right` need `RPAREN`.  I'm not sure whether you need `%nonassoc` at all.  I'm assume that the `'code'(` at the start and the `)'code'` at the end are artefacts of trying to format a comment.  Normally, you want ADD and SUB at a lower priority than MULT and DIV.

Answer (score 0):

The issues are fairly well covered in the [GNU bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Why-Precedence.html#Why-Precedence).

As @Jonathan Leffler says:

> You need to specify the precedence and associativity of the operators. Look up `%left`, `%right` and `%nonassoc`. Or write the grammar in a different manner altogether. For example, the grammar in the C standard doesn't need the precedence levels or associativity.
>
> The `%token` items look plausible. I think `%left` does not need `LPAREN`; nor does `%right` need RPAREN. I'm not sure whether you need `%nonassoc` at all. I'm assume that the `'code'(` at the start and the `)'code'` at the end are artefacts of trying to format a comment. Normally, you want ADD and SUB at a lower priority than MULT and DIV.

In the arithmetic example these are usually resolved by writing the grammar as:

```
expression : term
           | term ADD expression
           | term SUB expression
            ;

term : factor
     | factor MULT term
     | factor DIV term
     ;

factor : VARNAME
       | DIGIT
       | LPAREN expression RPAREN
       ;
```

Now you have both the associativity and the precedence of the operators defined in an unambiguous grammar.